# Exit edit mode from a control hosted in a cell

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, editmode

I have a custom datagridviewcolumn, a custom control hosted in a cell. I want to programmatically exit edit mode and validate the current value in the cell (this value is correct). I have checked below ways but without success:

```
this.datagridview.currentCell.datagridview.endEdit()
this.EditingControlDataGridView.endEdit()
this.datagridview.endEdit();
```

also by forcing the current cell to change:

```
this.datagridview.currentCell = this.datagridview.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[columnIndex]
```

I need to programmatically force the commit of the pending value in the cell because for example, there are cases that I need to delete a row of datagridview but as cell (in the same row being deleted) is in edit mode, I cannot do it if I do not commit changes for the cell and exit edit mode before.

Also, I have similar strange behaviour when I want to exit edit mode but, in this case, discarding the changes in the cell: depending on the state of my application, sometimes doing this.datagridview.CancelEdit() works and sometimes not.

Using C#, .NET Framework 4.0, WinForms.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code

```
Application.DoEvents();
```

to force the event to fire: